# Как к жадной загрузке добавить параметры в laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, запрос

Всем привет.
У меня есть жадная загрузка в запросе with(['filter_value'
Как сюда принудительно добавить массив с параметрами, например нужно включить в filter_value с id = [111,222,333].

Т.е я сначала отсеил параметры где нет товаров, чтобы пользователю их не показывали (т.к таких товаров нет с такими параметрами), а теперь нужно добавить принудительно эти параметры с id = 111, id = 222, id = 333

```
$filter = Filter::where('on_off', 1)
    ->whereHas('category_filter', function ($query) use ($category_one) {
        $query->where('category_id', $category_one->id);
    })
    ->whereHas('product_filter', function ($query) use ($product) {
        $query->whereIn('product_id', $product->pluck('id'));
    })
    ->with(['filter_value' => function ($query) use ($product) {        // жадная загрузка 'filter_value'
        $query->whereHas('product_filter', function ($query) use ($product) {
            $query->where('product_id', $product->pluck('id'));
    
        });
        //$query->where('id', 116);
    }])
    ->get()
    ->sortBy('id');
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно воспользоваться оператором IN:

```
$query->whereHas('product_filter', function ($query) use ($product) {
        $query->where('product_id', $product->pluck('id'));
})->whereIn('id', [111, 222, 333]);
```

Если айдишники нужно получиться извне, то используем тот же use, чтобы пробросить данные.

Вроде ничего сложного. Я ответил на вопрос? Соотвественно IN можно использовать на любом уровне, если необходимо. Для того, чтобы посмотреть на то, какой запрос формирует Eloquent, можно использовать `->toSql();`. Мне это помогает лучше понимать свои действия.

Comment: спасибо за ответ, но $filter->filter_value[] = пусто

Comment: ->toSql(); - нужно дебажить запрос. Я не знаю ни структуры таблиц, ни самих таблиц, ни их связей. И лучше сделать это самостоятельно, чтобы понимать свои действия.